# Faults are coming while saving data using Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fault

I am using core data to save data of my iOS app. Its multi-threaded app; Multiple threads can save data into Core Data DB. Actually, Faults are coming while saving data using Core Data.

Here is the piece of code where faults are printing out:

```
 public func saveChanges()
{
    self.managedObjectContext.performBlock { () -> Void in

        if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                //Handle Error
                //Handle Error, offcourse we will return after that
                print("======================================================")
                print("Error while saving 1rd tier context")
                print("------------------------------------------------------")

                let saveError = error as NSError

                print("Unable to Save Note")
                //print("\(saveError), \(saveError.localizedDescription)")

                let detailedErrors = saveError.userInfo[NSDetailedErrorsKey] as? [NSError]

                if let _ = detailedErrors {
                    for detailedError:NSError in detailedErrors! {
                        print("----------------------------------------")
                        print(" DetailedError:\(detailedError.userInfo)")
                        print("----------------------------------------")
                    }
                }

                print("------------------------------------------------------")
                print("\(saveError.localizedDescription)")
                print("======================================================")

                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the logs on console(Showing short form of logs):

```
 DetailedError:[Dangling reference to an invalid object.: <null>, NSValidationErrorValue: Relationship 'emails' on managed object (0x7ff2149f9220) <UserDB: 0x7ff2149f9220> (entity: UserDB; id: 0x7ff214a20270 <x-coredata:///UserDB/t45022E2A-2772-4525-8D96-929D1AC8FD7D8> ; data: {
addressBookContacts =     (
);
bio = nil;
```

And some more:

```
)}, NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey: (
"<Email: 0x7ff214d05c40> (entity: Email; id: 0x7ff214a6d420 <x-coredata:///Email/t45022E2A-2772-4525-8D96-929D1AC8FD7D9> ; data: {\n    emailRemovedByUser = nil;\n    \"email_address\" = nil;\n    \"email_type\" = nil;\n    id = 0;\n    \"is_verified\" = nil;\n    \"social_media_source\" = nil;\n    user = \"0x7ff214a20270 <x-coredata:///UserDB/t45022E2A-2772-4525-8D96-929D1AC8FD7D8>\";\n    visibility = 0;\n})"`), NSValidationErrorObject: <UserDB: 0x7ff2149f9220> (entity: UserDB; id: 0x7ff214a20270 <x-coredata:///UserDB/t45022E2A-2772-4525-8D96-929D1AC8FD7D8> ; data: {
addressBookContacts =     (
```

Its also showing "Dangling reference to an invalid object"; I am stuck with the issue.. and can't understand why this is happening.

Anyone observed this type of issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is really dangerous to manage Core Data from multiple thread.

You have only 2 ways to work with CD :

- Thread confinement : All you call to read/write core data are made on the same thread ( generally this is the main thread )
- Multi Context : You create one managed object context by thread, but this is really hard and you don't want to do that

So I recommande you to use the main thread to perform all of your calls. ( and check if your context is really set up in the main thread too )

Comment: Let me try with it. Thanks for your response.